# Handle Click- Events of Dynamically generated buttons..?? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, button, event-handling

HI,
Am on creation of touch screen UI system.And am generating button for selecting products

Under certain category.

--> array of button creating dynamically And placing in TABPAGE when user selects Tab for category.
The button will be created with the name of products, Under the category selected.

{
'the way am creating controls.
mybutton(j) = new button()
mybutton(j).top = 100
}

How can i get the Click event of those buttons-( in the array)....??

Comment: Desktop application or Web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link. http://forums.asp.net/p/1583639/3997438.aspx

Add button into the list and create a event for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+=` operator to assign a handler to an event, for example:

```
myButton.Click += ButtonClick;
```

and then declare it like this:

```
public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if the code is short, you may like to specify it right there directly, for example:

```
myButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    // ...
}
```

The advantage of that latter method is that you can capture outside variables, such as for example the array of buttons and the index of this particular button.

Comment: sorry, i dint get this..!!  Am using VB.NEt

Comment: @pvaju896: Next time you ask a question about VB.NET, **don’t tag it as c#.** (Duh.)